# Is the submission number in EasyChair random or indicative of the total number of submissions already created?

Tags: paper-submission, software

I submitted my paper in EasyChair website and I got a submission number 3100. My supervisor told me that this is a random number and it is not the real number of all submissions before mine. Is any information available on this that I could show him?

I've already checked a lot of websites but did not get any information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: It depends on the configuration of the conference.

In the configuration of a conference you can choose between two models: submission ids or submission numbers. If this option is set to *numbers*, then submissions will be numbered consecutively: 1, 2, 3 etc. If you use *ids*, submissions will be assigned random ids between 0100 and 9999.

As an author, you cannot be really sure which is being used, unless you consider the probability of 3099 submissions being negligible.

Source: *easychair* configuration help

Comment: Nice answer, but it would probably help to also link to the source.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I know, but I can only see this documentation when logged in

Comment: I contacted the chair of the conference, he told me that the number is a random id.